# How can I create a dynamic navigation system by loading a page into a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I am trying to create a navigation system where there is a set of links, that when clicked, will load an external page into a div. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="link1" class="loadPage"><div class="col-md-4"><div class="navActive">Link1</div></div></a>
    <a href="link2" class="loadPage"><div class="col-md-4"><div class="">Link2</div></div></a>
    <a href="link3" class="loadPage"><div class="col-md-4"><div class="">Link3</div></div></a>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loadPage').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var curActive = document.querySelectorAll(".navActive");
        for (i=0;i<curActive.length;i++)
            curActive[i] = curActive[i].className.replace( /(?:^|\s)navActive(?!\S)/g , '' );
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.targetLoad')
            .hide()
            .load(this.href), function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(500);
            });
        $(this + ' div div').addClass('navActive');
    });
});
```

Comment: Syntax error? Open dev tools (F12). `.load(this.href*)*, f` to begin with.

Comment: I don't get any errors from the code, it just doesn't work. @yury-tarabanko

Comment: There is an error provided that you copied it right. Incorrent parenthesis `function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(500);
            }); \\<-- ?`

Comment: That's so weird. I wasn't getting that error (Safari 7.0.3). Thanks for the solution though! @yury-tarabanko

Comment: No problem. :) I do recommend to install Chrome or Firefox (with Firebug). They have excellent dev tools onboard. :)

Comment: I do have both installed (plus opera and ie on a virtual machine), I just prefer safari because it tends to conform to the W3 spec a little bit better than the other two. Plus, there's iCloud and what not. @yury-tarabanko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your code:

1. `.load(this.href*)*, function() {...);` should be `.load(this.href, function() {`. You want to specify a complete callback. Not just declare a function expression, right?
2. `this div div` what's that? You need `$(this).find('div > div')`.

Summarizing it up.

```
$(function() {
    $('.loadPage').click(function(e){
        var activeCls = 'navActive';
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.' + activeCls).removeClass(activeCls);
        $('.targetLoad')
            .hide()
            .load(this.href, function() {//there is no ')' after href
                $(this).fadeIn(500);
            });
        $(this).find('div > div').addClass(activeCls);
    });
});
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/F4EL9/. Ignore additional code to emulate server response.

Answer (score -2):

Consider doing something like this:

```
<a onclick="load_url('/my-page.html');">My page</a>
```

And then the jquery:

```
function load_url(url)
{
    $("#target_div").load(url);
}
```

Comment: Inline handlers. Year 2014 out there.

Comment: That would work, but I agree with @yury-tarabanko . No inline event handlers.